# Change view from adapter android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a bottom sheet  dialog fragment containing a RecyclerView, in the RecyclerView adapter I have list of items to choose, and if a user chooses one item, a TextView in the fragment should change colour and text.

Adapter:

```
public class ServiceStaffAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServiceStaffAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<StaffMoreStoreList> StaffMoreStoreItems;
private Context context;
private SharedPreferences spStore;
private ArrayList<String> staffArray, initialsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
private View vDialogService;
private String staffArrayString, staffIdString;

public ServiceStaffAdapter(List<StaffMoreStoreList> StaffMoreStoreItems, Context context){
    super();
    this.StaffMoreStoreItems = StaffMoreStoreItems;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public ServiceStaffAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_staff_list, parent, false);
    ServiceStaffAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new ServiceStaffAdapter.ViewHolder(v);

    SharedPreferences sp2= context.getSharedPreferences("STORE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    staffArrayString = sp2.getString("staffArray","");
    staffArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(staffArrayString.equals("")){
        staffArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    }else{
        String replace = staffArrayString.replace("[","");
        String replace1 = replace.replace("]","");
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>    (Arrays.asList(replace1.split(",")));
        staffArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String fav:arrayList){
            staffArray.add(String.valueOf(fav.trim()));
        }
    }
    //array of string for staffs selected
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ServiceStaffAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final StaffMoreStoreList staffMoreStoreList =  StaffMoreStoreItems.get(position);

    holder.tvStaffName.setText(staffMoreStoreList.getStaffName());


    StaffMoreStoreItems.get(position).getStaffId();
    Log.e("staffArray size", String.valueOf(staffArray.size()));
    Log.e("staff array", staffArray.toString());
    staffIdString = staffMoreStoreList.getStaffId();
    //pre-select staffs    
    if(staffArray.contains(StaffMoreStoreItems.get(position).getStaffId())){
        holder.profile_image.setBorderColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary));

    }else{
        holder.profile_image.setBorderColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.transparent));
    }

    holder.cardStaff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(staffArray.contains(staffMoreStoreList.getStaffId())){
                holder.profile_image.setBorderColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.transparent));
                staffArray.removeAll(Collections.singleton(staffMoreStoreList.getStaffId()));

            }else{
                holder.profile_image.setBorderColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary));
                staffArray.add(staffMoreStoreList.getStaffId());

            }

            spStore = context.getSharedPreferences("STORE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = spStore.edit();
            editor1.putString("staffArray", staffArray.toString());           
            editor1.commit();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return StaffMoreStoreItems.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    private TextView tvStaffName;
    private CardView cardStaff;
    private CircleImageView profile_image;
    private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvStaffName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStaffName);
        cardStaff = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardStaff);
        profile_image = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    }
  }
}
```

While clicking on CardViews in adapter I want to change a TextView in my fragment containing the RecyclerView. TextView will change accordingly on the size of staffArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy this inside you Adapter. creating an Interface to perform onClick.

```
public interface OnClickListner {
void setOnItemClick(int postion, View view);
```

}

then create an instance in you adapter `OnClickListner onClickListner ;`

then create a setter `public void setOnClickListner(OnClickListner onClickListner ) {
        this.onClickListner = onClickListner ;
    }`

now in OnBind

```
holder.myview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onClickListner .setOnItemClick(position,view);
    }
});
```

then in Your fragment paste these.

```
adapter.setOnClickListner(this);
```

them error will come, hower mouse there it will ask you to implement onclick,
implement method and do whatever you want to do in fragment,

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have followed your step but on the final step I cannot resolve the method .setOnClickListner()

Comment: in adapter you must create a setter for onclick. adapter.yourSetterMethod(this);